# How to call controller method after authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have following metod in controller:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/api/users/login", consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(OK)
public TokenResponse login(@RequestBody LoginUserRequest loginUserRequest, Principal principal) {
    return new TokenResponse().setAccessToken("token");
}
```

here is a `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
            .formLogin().disable()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/users/login").permitAll()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(mobileAuthenticationFilter(objectMapper), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .addFilter(new JwtAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(), super.userDetailsService()));
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);

    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
            .usersByUsernameQuery("SELECT login, pass, active FROM users WHERE login = ?")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("SELECT login, 'ROLE_USER' FROM users WHERE login = ?")
            .passwordEncoder(new CustomPasswordEncoder());
}

@Bean
public MobileAuthenticationFilter mobileAuthenticationFilter(ObjectMapper objectMapper) throws Exception {
    MobileAuthenticationFilter mobileAuthenticationFilter = new MobileAuthenticationFilter(objectMapper);
    mobileAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
    mobileAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler((request, response, authentication) -> {
        System.out.println(request);
    });
    return mobileAuthenticationFilter;
}
```

`MobileAuthenticationFilter` is reading from json body and prepare `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`

```
public class MobileAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public MobileAuthenticationFilter(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        super(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/users/login"));
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            reader.mark(0);
            LoginUserRequest loginUserRequest = objectMapper.readValue(sb.toString(), LoginUserRequest.class);
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginUserRequest.getLogin(), loginUserRequest.getPassword());
            return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(token);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

this code works fine but is one thing which I want to archive.

After successfully authentication, response is produced immediately by the:

```
mobileAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler((request, response, authentication) -> {
    System.out.println(request);
});
```

Here ofcourse I can return something to client (in body), but there is any possibility to invoke controller method `public TokenResponse login` and that method should return a response (based on method contract and annotations for http code)?

This method in controller in that scenario is never called.

Comment: Why isn't the client just sending a request to /api/users/login to login? If it does the controller method will be called.

Comment: @Cyril are you thinking about, simple call to controller, without any filters, which authenticates user? And inside that controller method will be an authentication handling (producing response on success or throwing unauthorized exception)?

Answer (score 1):

Would there be a formLogin, you could have used the `successHandler(...)` to redirect to the page you want. Note that you have to also think about error responses.

Since you have explicitly disabled *formLogin*, I recommend if users call */api/users/login* instead of authenticating them in `attemptAuthentication(...)`.

So, as you have put it `..addFilterBefore(mobileAuthenticationFilter(objectMapper), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)`, your filter will be triggered populating the resulting response.

Your controller will look like something like this:

```
public TokenResponse login(@Valid @RequestBody LoginUserRequest loginUserRequest) {
   //may be check for AuthenticationException
   try{
       ...
       generateToken(loginUserRequest.getUserName(), loginUserRequest.getPassword());
       ...
   } catch(AuthenticationException ex){
        // status = HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED;
   } catch (Exception ex) {
        //status = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
   }
}
```

```
public String generateToken(String name, String password) {
        try {
            // check for null or empty
            
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken upToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, password, new ArrayList<>());
            Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(upToken);
            
            // do whatever operations you need and return token 
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! I thought about moving authentication logic into controller method and ommit that filter. That AuthenticationManager is injected into controller? And throwing exception will be enought?